# Button Background in xml

Tags: java, xml, button, layout, background

I have a button and I want to replace the background I designed with the paste.
But there is no change in it.

where is the problem from ?

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button_signIn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/et_back"
        android:text="@string/button_signIn"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try.  `android:background="@drawable/et_back"` **replace to**  `android:backgroundTint="@drawable/et_back"` it might work.